# Returning Line Number on exit() in PHP

Tags: php

If I have this code in PHP :

```
if($statement == 'false') {
   return 0;
   exit();
}
```

As you know, exit() will stop the script from running. Is it possible to return the line number of where the exit() runs?

So it'll return exit() on line 3 (Based on above code)

Thank you!

Comment: In your example, since you do a `return` first, the `exit()` will never be called.

Comment: If you're trying to do some kind of error handling, you might want to consider logging the error details rather than just outputting the line number to the browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP has a constant called `__LINE__` that outputs the current line in your script. You can also pass a message to `exit()`, so you can simply combine the two:

```
exit('Terminated on line ' . __LINE__);
```

Comment: +1, it would be also useful to know which file threw the exception:  

`exit('Terminated on line ' . __LINE__ . ' in ' . __FILE__);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `debug_backtrace` to know the number of the line when this function is executed.

debug_backtrace return an array and you can retrive the line with

```
$trace = debug_backtrace();
```

in this array $trace, you can get function, line, file, class, object...

or use this magic constant [**__*LINE*__**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

```
echo __LINE__;
```

> the value of **LINE** depends on the line that it's used on in your
>   script